# Email delivery failure - bounceback address

Tags: email

I've been looking for documentation on the standard behaviour for mail servers who fail to deliver their mail.

I want the 'From' field to be different from the account that receives emails when there is a delivery failure.

E.g.

My program sends an email from 'donotreply@example.com', and on failure to deliver I want to be sent the delivery failure bounceback at 'failedemails@example.com'.

Is this accomplished by setting the reply-to? Or should I login with the 'failedemails' account and therefore it will receive the email back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can try, but I think that bounces are typically going to be sent to the envelope sender. This means that sending the mail from donotreply@example.com using your failedemails account is probably your best bet.

You can also try these headers:

```
Reply-To: failedemails@example.com
Errors-To: failedemails@example.com
Return-Path: failedemails@example.com
```

A similar question was also asked here: [Set email headers so bounced emails go to a specific address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303541/set-email-headers-so-bounced-emails-go-to-a-specific-address)