# Controlling where "out of office" replies are sent

Tags: email, smtp, mail-server, email-bounces

How do mail servers decide when and where to send "out of office"-type autoreplies?

It seems this is mail server dependent, so some will use a reply-to: address, others the From: and perhaps the Sender: address. Some servers (or all?) seem to care about the Precedence: field and will not send out of office replies at all on Precedence:bulk (or maybe precedence:list?). The return-path seems to be used for more severe types of bounces, but maybe it's used as well?

What I want is to achieve (this time) is to minimize the number of response e-mails that go to the from: address. I don't mind getting them at the reply-to address.

I've been looking for some sort of reference or best practices - any references or suggestions? I 've looked at some relevant RFCs ([RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), [RFC3834](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834)) but I'm looking for how things are actually handled.

Comment: Some similar SO questions: 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5303541/350651, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1235534/350651

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few thoughts:

- do not send more than one reply per day and recipient (flood
  protection)
- don't reply to anything that looks "automated"  (bulk,
  spam, mailing lists, ...).
- the reply should set "Auto-Submitted:
  auto-replied' and 'Precedence: bulk' headers

have a look at this example to see possible header and senderpatterns to detect automated senders:
https://github.com/gryphius/fuglu/blob/master/fuglu/src/fuglu/plugins/vacation.py

This implementation only sends to the envelope sender address(Return-Path), In my opinion, out-of-office is basically the same as a "your message is deferred" error and should therefore go to the bounce address. But I rarely see Reply-To Headers in non-bulk anyway,

Comment: Thanks, but I'm rather on the other end this time - I'm not trying to SEND out of office replies, I'm sending other e-mails and I'm curious if there are known rules for where the autoreplies will go.

Comment: @PapaFreud I think this answer sums it up though. What I did was created a suite that checks for those headers, and if they're there, they get ignored. Testing now.. I'll let you know..